¿Cómo agregar una columna, la cual sin importar los registros que existen, el primer registro sea 0, despues 1, despues 2 y se reinicie?
tengo el siguiente codigo:
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2024-01-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '2024-04-11';
WITH DateRange AS (

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate) AS Date
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate) < @endDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date)
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date) < @endDate
)
SELECT *
FROM DateRange

En el cual me traer todas las fechas que hay entre la fecha inicio y la fecha final, lo que necesito es poder tener una columna en la cual sin importar los registros que existan, el primer registro sea 0, despues el segundo sea el 1, el que sigue sea el 2 y al llegar al 2 se reinicie y vuelva a comenzar, 0,1,2,0,1,2 asi a todos los registros que existan.
Ojala alguien tenga una solucion. Gracias

ve la definición de la función ROW_NUMBER() quizás te ayude (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)

DATEADD no es válido en MySQL. Es DATE_ADD. (O solamente + INTERVAL 1 DAY como en el SQL Standard). Además, es necesario de usar RECURSIVE en una consulta recursiva en MySQL.

No me queda claro que resultado quieres obtener. Puedes incluir un ejemplo del resultado para un rango de fechas más pequeño, digamos de 2 o 3 días.

Por otro lado el código que publicas no parece de mysql, seguro que ese es el motor que utilizas?

Si substraes la primera fecha de la fecha en tu resultado, recibes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. De esto tomas el módulo de 3, y ¡ya!
WITH RECURSIVE DateRange (Date) AS (
    SELECT @startDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    WHERE @startDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @endDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE Date + INTERVAL 1 DAY < @endDate
)
SELECT Date, DATEDIFF(Date, @startDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY) % 3
FROM DateRange
ORDER BY Date;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/NnHNs76n
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) - 1) % 3

resulta en los mismos valores.
